# Error with package.json

Tags: json, mean, package.json

I am running 'npm build' and 'npm start' in the root directory of my mean.js application, but I am encountering the following errors:

```
npm ERR! file /Users/developer/dev-projects/everest-web/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 162 while parsing
'{
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "meanauthapp",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "version": '

npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
"name": "meanauthapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "MEAN stack authentication app",
"main": "app.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "node app"
"ng": "ng"
},
"dependencies": {
"express": "4.16.2",
"mongoose": "4.13.6",
"bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
"cors": "2.8.4",
"jsonwebtoken": "8.1.0",
"body-parser": "1.18.2",
"passport": "0.4.0",
"passport-jwt": "3.0.1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "MIT",
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.0"
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have comma after "start": "node app"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check for "Failed to parse JSON" errors is pasting the file content into a validator.

I recommend:

https://jsonlint.com/

Press "Validate JSON" and the missing comma in line 7 is clearly highlighted.